# How to select instances for specific 'n' on m:n relationships?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have two models Teacher and Category. These two have Many to Many relationship.

I want to get those teachers who have one category equal to "OLevels". Which method of eloquent is used for it or is there any other way I can get it?

Is there anyway to get it as:

```
$teachers = Teacher::where('category', '=', 'OLevels')->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `whereHas` for that:

```
$category = 'OLevels';
$teachers = Teacher::whereHas('category', function($q) use ($category){
    $q->where('name', $category);
})->get();
```

Comment: `$teachers = Teacher::whereHas('category', function($q){
    $q->where('name', $category);
})->get();`  I want to use variable $category in it, but its scope is not available in closure function... How can I get the value of $category in it?

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of eager loading with constraints

```
$teachers = Teacher::with(['category' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('category', '=', 'OLevels');

}])->get();
```

Further info in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading).

Comment: $teachers = Teacher::with(['category' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('category', '=', $category);

}])->get();   I want to use variable $category in it, but its scope is not available in closure function... How I will get the value of $category in it?

Comment: Eager This isn't what the OP asked for. He wants to filter `teachers` no the the eager loaded category collection. `whereHas` should be used.